# Script to run before Windows backup

Tags: windows-7, script, windows-backup

I need to write a script to check the size of the disk that our backups store to on client machines and decide if it needs to delete the oldest backup set so the current days backup can run.

Is there a correct way to have Windows launch a script before the Windows Backup runs, or do I just use a batch job to run the script with a time before the Windows backup does its stuff.

Comment: To be clear.. You're asking for the best way to run the script before the backup, not for the actual Size-check script itself, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd get a windows event indicating "Backup starting". What you're better off doing is create a scheduled task that runs your script to check folder size and then use the following command 
**wbadmin start systemstatebackup -backuptarget (backup location you resolved in the last step)**